# TextField not work as expected. Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I try to build a basic calculator. I want that textField to work as a calculator (press for example 154 and display to be 154) when I click button numbers. Unfortunalty I don't get the proper result. When I click 9 for example I get 0123456789. I don't know how to pass the button int into and array and then to retrieve as a string.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Buttons {
    public static List<JButton> generateButtons(JFrame frame) {
    List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    int x = 20;
    int y = 500;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String str = Integer.toString(i);
        buttons.add(new JButton(str));
        buttons.get(i).setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);
        x += 60;
        frame.add(buttons.get(i));
        if (x >= 380) {
            x = 20;
            y = 430;
        }
    }
    return buttons;
}
    public static String displayOnTextField(List<JButton> list,JTextField field){
        int number = 0;
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <list.size(); i++){
            String returned = Integer.toString(i);
            str += returned;
            String finalStr = str;
            list.get(i).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    field.setText(finalStr);
                }
            });
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

And main:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();

    List<JButton> list =  Buttons.generateButtons(frame);
    String displayOnTextField = Buttons.displayOnTextField(list,textField);


    frame.setSize(400,600);
    textField.setBounds(150,40,150,30);
    frame.add(textField);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are appending string in a loop which you are getting from a button stored in list as below

```
            String returned = Integer.toString(i);
            str += returned;
            String finalStr = str;
```

so for button **0** final string will be 0 for button 1 final string will be **01** and so on

instead you can do as follows:
Change your **finalStr** strings assignment to

```
String finalStr =  Integer.toString(i);
```

and in **actionPerformed** method set text as follows

```
field.setText(field.getText() + finalStr);
```

It will work for you...

Comment: One more problem, I want to return the final string...how I can do it?

Comment: and when it should return on button click?

Comment: For example I want 150. I press 1,5 ,0. It will get displayed but in same time I want to get 150 as a string to implement in further things, like calculations. Undestand?

Comment: so you will perform further things  on some event what will be that event can you tell me that event?

Comment: After I get the string, I want to put in in a list. After the list will be filled for example if I press "+", list will make a sum from the returned strings of displayOnTextField method.

Comment: please ask different question with explanation how you want to achieve your functionality

Comment: Hello, I rewrite whole code and now it's working perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The string you are appending is `finalStr`, which you build in a loop.

```
    String returned = Integer.toString(i);
    str += returned;
    String finalStr = str;
```

If you don't want it to append the preceding characters, don't use `+=`. You could simply use:

```
    String finalStr = Integer.toString(i);
```

Comment: I know, but the problem is that if I do as you suggested, if I press for example 5 I get 5, but then if I press 4 I get 4, not 54..

Comment: So then you need to append the string to what you're passing to `setText`: `field.setText(field.getText() + finalStr);`